# Can i delete BackgroundDownload.exe of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Because of this process, my computer's cpu share is skyrocketing sometimes. As far as I know, the function of this file is automatic update of visual studio 2019. I don't really want an update. If i need an update in the future, i can do it manually. Therefore, if the function of this executable file is only a simple update, and deleting does not interfere with the use of Visual Studio 2019, i want to delete the executable file. Is there any problem if I delete it?

Comment: You could just turn off auto-updates for VS and extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I just turned on Controlled Folder Access after that BackgroundDownloader.exe does not get any access to download anything in the background and thus saves CPU share, Try once it will not only stop these types of background downloading it will also save you from many troublesome activities.